# jQuery Replace image on mouse hover left, right

Tags: jquery

I've got two images I want to load when my mouse goes left or right within my DIV. I can't figure out the fadeIn for it as I want the new images to fade in on hover and fade out as well. Please help! Currently the fade in doesn't work and I can't seem to figure it out :( I've just learnt JS in the past two days so any noob help would be great!

```
<div id="infruition-rollover">
<img id="default" src="" width="990" height="411"/>
<img class="off" src="InfruitionWIAYLeftRollover.jpg" width="990" height="411" />
<img class="off" src="InfruitionWIAYRightRollover.jpg" width="990" height="411" />
</div>
</body>

<script language="javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
console.log("hello!");

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#default').attr('src','InfruitionWIAYNoRollover.jpg');

$('#infruition-rollover').mousemove(function(e){
    if (e.pageX < 450) {
        console.log("Entered Left: "+e.pageX);
        $('#default').fadeIn(100,function() {
        $(this).attr('src','InfruitionWIAYLeftRollover.jpg');
        })
        }
    else {
        console.log("Entered Right: "+e.pageX);
        $('#default').fadeIn(100,function() {
            $(this).attr('src','InfruitionWIAYRightRollover.jpg');})

        }
})
})
</script>
```

Comment: Have you included the jqueryLibraries?

Answer (score 0):

Check this example I did for you:

HTML

```
<div id="infruition-rollover">
<img id="default" src="" width="990" height="411"/>
<img class="off" src="http://www-static.weddingbee.com/pics/36694/head.jpeg" width="100" height="100" />
<img class="off" src="http://www.random.org/analysis/randbitmap-rdo.png" width="100" height="100" />
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
console.log("hello!");

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#default').attr('src','InfruitionWIAYNoRollover.jpg');

$('#infruition-rollover').mousemove(function(e){
    if (e.pageX < 100) {
        console.log("Entered Left: "+e.pageX);
        $('#default').fadeIn(100,function() {
        $(this).attr('src','http://www-static.weddingbee.com/pics/36694/head.jpeg');
        })
        }
    else {
        console.log("Entered Right: "+e.pageX);
        $('#default').fadeIn(100,function() {
        $(this).attr('src','http://www.random.org/analysis/randbitmap-rdo.png');

        })

        }
})
})
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3vjgxbfg/)

Comment: Hi Joakim, thanks for your quick post. Unfortunately this doesn't fadein :( I've got the rollovers working it's just the fadein that doesn't work. Ideally a fadeout as well would be awesome but I can't figure it out :(

(Oh - I'm working locally so the images aren't full paths but it works)